# Rails form_tag No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have routes

```
  post '/request/:payment_system' => 'new_domain/accounts#withdraw_request', constraints: { payment_system: /webmoney|visa|mastercard|bank|qiwi|ym|neteller|skrill/ }
```

and form_tag

```
 form_tag({ action: :withdraw_request}) do
```

my controller action

```
class NewDomain::AccountsController < ApplicationController

    def withdraw_request
      some code here
    end
end
```

but i have got

```
No route matches {:action=>"withdraw_request", :controller=>"new_domain/accounts"
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Please post, result of `rake routes`

Answer (score 0):

Assume you need a collection route,Puts this codes in your routes.rb:

```
 namespace :new_domain do
   resources :accounts, only: [] do
      collection do
        get :withdraw_request
      end
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

`form_tag({ action: :withdraw_request}) do`
It will make  post '/request/:payment_system' useless, where is the payment_system value and where is /request?

If you really want to make a POST request to withdraw_request, you need to make a collection.